# Firefox absolute position bug

Tags: html, css, firefox, browser, css-position

I'm having problem with absolute position in firefox. It works different than Chrome, IE or Opera.

I'm talking about navigation here http://mapylasky.xdiv.cz/

In all browsers expect Firefox they are in one line. In Firefox they are not in place.

```
.menu-item{
     position: absolute;
     color: #000;
 }

 .menu-item .icon{
     position: absolute;
     background-image: url('<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/img/menu/menu-icons.png');
  }

  .menu-item .desc{
      position: absolute;
      font-size: 16px;
   }

.container{
    width: 1100px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

 .menu-item .icon{
   height: 56px;
  }

.menu-item.prvni{
    left: 11px;
    top: 21px;
}

.menu-item.prvni .icon{
    width: 193px;
    height: 92px;
    background-position-x: 452px;
}

.menu-item.prvni .desc{
    left: 0px;
    top: 0px;
}
```

HTML

```
        <div class="navigation-background">
            <div class="container">


                    <a href="javascript: void(0)" onclick="scrollToAnchor('uvod');">
                        <div class="menu-item prvni active" id="home-menu">
                            <div class="icon"></div>
                        </div>
                    </a>


             </div>
        </div>
```

What am I doing wrong?

JSFiffle: https://jsfiddle.net/2cne0fnc/

Comment: People are unlikely to click on the link to your website, given your user status. Post a simplified JSFiddle of your problem, or at least post some relevant markup/css/js, then we can help :)

Comment: You're right, here is JSFiffle
https://jsfiddle.net/2cne0fnc/ Works allright in Chrome, Opera...but not working in firefox (icons are mostly invisible - out of place)

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not support `background-position-x`, but does support `background-position`

Simply change your `background-position-x: 100px` to `background-position:100px 0` to include both the x and y position.

Working example : https://jsfiddle.net/41xb9xfb/

Comment: Great, one part of problem is solved, thank you!
But icons are still 16px higher. Seems like one of elements is wrong positioned.